# How to resolve a failed assert - zmqpp::frame::~frame(): assertion `0 == result' failed?

Tags: c++, zeromq, assertion

I am using **`zeromqpp`** to send data to another process. I have successfully used `zeromqpp` with other signals but with my last message added to the producer I frequently get the run time assertion:

> `zmqpp::frame::~frame()68: assertion "0 == result" failed`

The consumer program never gets the error, only the producer and it causes the producer's program to crash. If I remove the code that publishes the message then I don't see the assertion.

The `zeromq` server doesn't report any errors. `GDB` doesn't give me a stack trace and the assertion doesn't occur at the same time during multiple program executions, so I am having a hard time tracking down where the problem is. I have started commenting out large portions of code to try to narrow things down, but I am still lost as to the cause of the problem.

Can anyone tell me what this assertion error means so I can narrow down what to look for?

### Edit

Here is step 0.

```
    signalProducer_->publish(SIGNAL_NAME, producerData, 1, VALID_SIGNAL_DATA);
```

Comment: Could you post your **`assert`** SLOC + some source-code context "around" it? `assert` at least includes: a) the expression whose assertion failed ( **`result == 0 `** ), b) the name of the source file and c) the line number where it happened. So actually **-- what other doubts do you have once "narrowing down what to look for?"** If you read `ZeroMQ` **API** documentation, there are more details on this as ZeroMQ-team typically uses `result == 0` assertions to detect all the sorts of possible anomalies. More details are reported in *errno*.

Comment: @user3666197 In my original post I had already included the source file name, class name and function name where the assertion occurs. It is in fame.cpp in ~frame(). I however did forget the line number. I have added it now.

Comment: So, when are you planning to move to **`[Step 0]`**?

Comment: @user3666197 I don't understand your question "what other doubts do you have..."

Comment: @user3666197 Added step 0

Comment: Fine, so the `assert ( 0 == result )` is not your own SLOC, but some called function's one. So if you remove this line from the code, the rest is working smoothly, right?

Comment: Great, so trace forward in the source-code of the functions involved in this very single SLOC, to get to the place of the named **`assert ( 0 == result )`** & you are done, you have it.

Comment: That's the problem. I am unable to trace the code because there are no debug symbols for any code outside of my own. I have asked the author of the library I am using to send `ZeroMQ` messages for debug symbols but it has been over a week now with no luck.

Comment: This is why I was asking for help to understand this error, because I am new to `ZeroMQ` and I have no debug symbols to determine what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 0:

post also the very code, that actually started to generate the issue
see your own text

> *cit.:*" If I remove **the code** that publishes the message then I don't see the assertion."

---

### Step 1:

[Review the **`ZeroMQ`** low-level API documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/), not the actually used `c++` wrapper / binding implementation, for **pre-designed details** on error-causes recognised & distinguished at the lowest level, so as to realise and understand, what root-causes **may** appear in particular API-service-calls:

### Example:  <sup>...ØMQ team is particularly smart & pedantic on this since early releases- kudos</sup>

> The **`zmq_send()`** function shall return number of bytes in the message if successful. Otherwise it shall return **`-1`** and set ***errno*** to one of the values defined below.
> **Errors**
>   **`EAGAIN`** Non-blocking mode was requested and the message cannot be sent at the moment.
> **`ENOTSUP`** The `zmq_send()` operation is not supported by this socket type.
> **`EFSM`** The `zmq_send()` operation cannot be performed on this socket at the moment due to the socket not being in the appropriate state. This error may occur with socket types that switch between several states, such as `ZMQ_REP`. See the messaging patterns section of `zmq_socket(3)` for more information.
> **`ETERM`** The ØMQ context associated with the specified socket was terminated.
> **`ENOTSOCK`** The provided socket was invalid.
> **`EINTR`** The operation was interrupted by delivery of a signal before the message was sent.
> **`EHOSTUNREACH`** The message cannot be routed.

```
/*                                                     Send a multi-part
                                                       message consisting
                                                       of three parts to socket */
rc = zmq_send ( socket, "ABC",   3, ZMQ_SNDMORE );     assert (rc == 3);
rc = zmq_send ( socket, "DEFGH", 5, ZMQ_SNDMORE );     assert (rc == 5);

/*                                                     Final part;
                                                       no more parts to follow */
rc = zmq_send ( socket, "JK",    2, 0 );               assert (rc == 2);
```

Comment: That you for your response, I will look into this more. Unfortunately, I can't post the surrounding code as it is proprietary.

Comment: @Fred -- with all due respect, **one `SLOC` + a failed `assert`** are never proprietary.

Comment: Yes, you are correct one line of code is rarely proprietary. I had understood from your request that you wanted "surrounding code" which to me meant far more than one line.